# what is the different between man and man 3 unix commands?

Tags: unix, gnu, manpage

my question describes it all actually. I wanted to know what is the difference between `man` and `man 3` command to get the manual pages for unix commands?

Comment: Section 3 contains library functions.

Comment: You might want to see `man man`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UNIX command man pages are grouped in sections. See the section descriptions [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page).

General command line commands are in section 1. When you type `man command`, then `man` will give you the man page for `command` in the first section it finds it.

However, some commands may exist in more than one section. So if you have a shell command `read` and you type `man read`, you'll get the section 1 definition. But if you want the library call `read`, you would enter `man 3 read` which would tell `man` to go right to section 3 specifically.

Answer (score 1):

You can have identically named man pages in different sections. For example,

```
man 1 printf
```

will give you the manual for the `printf` command, while

```
man 3 printf
```

will give you the manual for the C library routine `printf`. If you don't specify a section number, you'll get the command from the first section that contains a match.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a number to `man`, you are telling it to look in exactly one section of the manual for the command in question.  (Practically speaking this means looking in a specific directory of `man` files.)  As it says in the `man` `man page`:

```
A section, if provided, will direct man to look only in that section of the manual.
The default action is to search in all of the available sections, following a pre-defined
order and to show only the first page found, even if page exists in several sections.
```

Section 3, in Linux, is typically reserved for functions within libraries, such as C/C++ libraries that happen to have `man` pages.